# Count the duration/length of a behavior

Tags: sas

I have a data set in SAS with different behaviors of a group like standing or lying.

Now I want to find out the duration of these behaviors whenever the hole group does the same thing (100% standing). I have a column with `lying100` which shows a 1 if 100% are lying and a 0 in any other case. I also create a column where I managed to mark  all the start points with `start` and the end of the observations with `end` (not sure if it's necessary though)

Now I want to find out how long each of these lying phase are (from start to end).

I imagine something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNaYl.jpg).

Comment: have you try anything

Comment: I tried first.variable and last.variable. The problem is that I can't sort the data with BY because I need to have it in that order to be able to determine the length.

Comment: Instead of a picture, can you type in the data as 'have' and then show the resultant data as 'want'.  Describe the logic behind marking an item as start and end. Decribe what you mean as length, is it the number of records from start to end, or the sum of the length values ? Also, include any tried code and the log warnings or errors that appear.

Comment: You can often use the NOTSORTED option on the BY group statement but it would really help if you showed sample data and what you expect as minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Like others, I am not exactly sure what exactly you want to achieve. 
This is what is my understanding. I guess you have dataset of patient's activity. It contains timestamp of measurement and result of the measurement (if it is standing or laying). Based on your input dataset from your image, I have created something like this:

```
data sequences(drop=lying100 length start_end);
    set test;
    BY NOTSORTED lying100;
    retain first_val;

    if FIRST.lying100 and lying100 eq 1 then
        first_val=length;

    if LAST.lying100 and lying100 eq 1 then
    do;
        duration=length-first_val;
        output;
        first_val=-1;
    end;
run;
```

And if you want to add timestamp in it, which sounds for me also kinda more reasonable, then the code would look something like this:

```
data sequences(drop=lying100 length start_end timeline);
  set test;
  BY NOTSORTED lying100;
  retain start_time;
  format start_time datetime20.;
  format end_time datetime20.;

  if FIRST.lying100 and lying100 eq 1 then do;
    start_time=timeline;
  end;

  if LAST.lying100 and lying100 eq 1 then
    do;
      end_time=timeline;
      duration=(end_time-start_time)/60;
      output;
    end;
run;
```

where

- start_time : would be the start time when the patient started laying
- end_time : would be the end of period when the patient was laying (he/she stood up)
- duration : amount of minutes the patient was laying

P.S. I did not use start_end column.

My test data to make my example complete:

```
data test;
  infile datalines delimiter=',';
  input lying100 length start_end $;
  datalines;
0,0,
0,0,
1,1,start
1,2,
1,3,
1,4,
1,5,end
0,0,
0,0,
1,1,start
1,2,
1,3,
1,4,
1,5,
1,6,end
0,0,
0,0,
;

data test;
  set test;
  format timeline datetime20.;
  retain timeline '07sep2018 10:00:00'dt;
  timeline=timeline+5*60;
run;
```